# C# - How to achieve multiple matching from a single string by using Linq and Regex?

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I have a string like: `var str = "My name is John, her name is Fonda and his name is Donald"`

and I have 3 objects in an enumerable set like:

```
var boy = new Person({name="John"});
var girl = new Person({name="Fonda"});
var son = new Person({name="Donald"});
new other = new Person({name="Mike"});
new other2 = new Person({name="Roger"});
```

Assume that the `resultSet` includes all those objects above.

```
var resultSet = new IEnumerable<Person>();
```

Here is my question:

I want to make Linq query on that set to return all the matched objects if they are in the given string.

I think it may well be achieved by using Regex but I don't know how :S

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Regex would be "(John|Fonda|Donald|Mike|Roger)", the pipe is an or statement, everything between is what is found.  What's between the parenthesis are the captured data.

Comment: Thanks Vince! It really helped me. I will try to construct the answer on top of it!

Comment: I haven't given my answer yet, but I'm thinking a PLINQ where each element (`boy, girl, son, other`, or `other2`) traverses the string in question (`My name is John, her name is Fonda and his name is Donald`) would be the direction you want to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Contains` method:

```
var str = "My name is John, her name is Fonda and his name is Donald";
var result= resultSet.Where(p=>str.Contains(p.name));
```

If you want to avoid partial results you can apply an `Split` to your sentence and do the following query using `Any` extension method:

```
var str = "My name is John, her name is Fonda and his name is Donald";
var strArray= str.Split( new [] {' ', ','});
var result= resultSet.Where(p=>strArray.Any(s=>s==p.name));
```

Comment: If `resultSet` contains name "Don" instead of name "Donald", then this approach will return object of "Don"

Comment: Added approach with `Split`, will not get "John" in the result, because of "," char

Comment: @Fabio, that's right, sorry, doing a lot of thing at the same time :)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it using LINQ:

```
var str = "My name is John, her name is Fonda and his name is Donald";
var strs = str.Split(new char[] {' ', ','}); //note the comma here is needed to get "John"
var names = from p in resultSet
            where strs.Contains(p.name)
            select p.name; //or select p if you need the "Person"
```

Note: most importantly, use `Contains` and `where` here

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

            var boy = new Person() {name="John"};
            var girl = new Person() {name="Fonda"};
            var son = new Person() {name="Donald"};
            var other = new Person() {name="Mike"};
            var  other2 = new Person(){name="Roger"};

            people.AddRange(new Person[] { boy, girl, son, other, other2 });

            string str = "My name is John, her name is Fonda and his name is Donald";

            string[] peopleInSentenance = people.Where(x => str.Contains(x.name)).Select(y => y.name).ToArray();
       }

    }
    public class Person
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
}
```